# Editing text file with Vim does not update tail -f

Tags: files, vim, tail

I'm using `tail -f a.txt` to watch updates on a file called `a.txt`.

If I update the file using something like `ls -a >> a.txt` in a second virtual console, the changes will display in real-time in the first one.

If I update the file using Vim in a second virtual console, the changes will not display in the first one.

I don't necessarily expect it to trigger an update in that window - but why exactly doesn't this update the terminal running the `tail -f` command?

Comment: `tail -f` checks for appends. `tail -F` checks for file renames.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you edit a file with `vim`, typically it reads the file into memory, then writes a new file. So `tail` is now operating on an out of date copy of the file (which remains in the file system until `tail` (and any other program) stops using it.

You can make `tail` follow the filename (rather than the file) by using:

```
tail -F yourfile
```

Note the *upper case* `F`.

Comment: `tail -F` works!  The console is now displaying a message like "a.txt has been replaced: following end of new file" and updates accordingly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

My understanding is that typically when editing with `vim`, you are editing a copy of the file, which is moved into place when you write your changes to disk.  Since this happens by `unlink`ing the original and `move`ing the new into place, `tail` does not see new changes to the original file.