# Why isn't tail command tracking the changes in a file in realtime?

Tags: files, tail

When I track a file in realtime using descriptor i.e `tail --follow=descriptor file_name`, it doesn't show the changes made in the file, whereas if i track the file in realtime using name i.e `tail --follow=name file_name`, it shows the changes made to the file. Also everytime i write to the file while tracking the file with tail using `--follow=name`, tail output shows that the file is removed and then reappears, here's the output `tail: file_name: No such file or directory`
`tail: 'file_name' has appeared;  following new file`, What is happening? Is the file being rewritten from beginning? Also is the descriptor of the file changing each time the file is written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you writing to the file?

What's happening is that when you write to the file you are either moving it or deleting it and then creating a new file with same name and then writing to the file. So when you use

1. --follow=name: tail will only care about the file_name, so before writing when you move/delete the file it tells you that `tail: file_name: No such file or directory` and when you create a file with same name it tells `tail: 'file_name' has appeared;  following new file` and it writes to the file and you can see the written content on the screen.
2. --follow=descriptor: tail will follow the file descriptor even after moving/deleting the file the file descriptor will point to the old file, you can verify this by going into `/proc/{tail process id}/fd`.

Comment: Is it always the case that a file is moved/deleted and then rewritten? Also if file descriptor doesn't change then why is it not able to track the changes and display the changes in realtime when using `follow=descriptor`?

Comment: @ShahFahad please tell how are you writing to the file? It isn't able to track the changes because you are writing to the new file and fd points to the older file, you can verify this by appending to the older file and you will be able to see the changes.

Comment: I am using the vim editor to write to file.

Comment: @ShahFahad see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/379982/255251.

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what i was looking for